# win32com equivalent of xlrd's sheet.ncols

Tags: python, excel, com, win32com, xlrd

xlrd makes it pretty easy to know what the last column is.

is there an easy way using win32com?

I have tried using ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count but this doesnt seem to give a correct answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's defined to give the count of **rows** in the **used range** (which may not start at cell `A1`). You need the number of **columns** in the **worksheet**.

Try something like this:

```
used = ws.UsedRange
nrows = used.Row + used.Rows.Count - 1
ncols = used.Column + used.Columns.Count - 1
```