# Why is win32com so much slower than xlrd?

Tags: python, win32com, xlrd

I have the same code, written using win32com and xlrd. xlrd preforms the algorithm in less than a second, while win32com takes minutes.

Here is the win32com:

```
def makeDict(ws):
"""makes dict with key as header name, 
   value as tuple of column begin and column end (inclusive)"""
wsHeaders = {} # key is header name, value is column begin and end inclusive
for cnum in xrange(9, find_last_col(ws)):
    if ws.Cells(7, cnum).Value:
        wsHeaders[str(ws.Cells(7, cnum).Value)] = (cnum, find_last_col(ws))
        for cend in xrange(cnum + 1, find_last_col(ws)): #finds end column
            if ws.Cells(7, cend).Value:
                wsHeaders[str(ws.Cells(7, cnum).Value)] = (cnum, cend - 1)
                break
return wsHeaders
```

And the xlrd

```
def makeDict(ws):
"""makes dict with key as header name, 
   value as tuple of column begin and column end (inclusive)"""
wsHeaders = {} # key is header name, value is column begin and end inclusive
for cnum in xrange(8, ws.ncols):
    if ws.cell_value(6, cnum):
        wsHeaders[str(ws.cell_value(6, cnum))] = (cnum, ws.ncols)
        for cend in xrange(cnum + 1, ws.ncols):#finds end column
            if ws.cell_value(6, cend):
                wsHeaders[str(ws.cell_value(6, cnum))] = (cnum, cend - 1)
                break
return wsHeaders
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(0) You asked "Why is win32com so much slower than xlrd?" ... this question is a bit like "Have you stopped beating your wife?" --- it is based on a presupposition that may not be true; win32com was written in C by a brilliant programmer, but xlrd was written in pure Python by an average programmer. The real difference is that win32com has to call COM which involves inter-process communication *and* was written by you-know-who, whereas xlrd is reading the Excel file directly. Moreover, there's a fourth party in the scenario: YOU. Please read on.

(1) You don't show us the source of the `find_last_col()` function that you use repetitively in the COM code. In the xlrd code, you are happy to use the same value (ws.ncols) all the time. So in the COM code, you should call `find_last_col(ws)` ONCE and thereafter used the returned result. **Update** See [answer to your separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968830/win32com-equivalent-of-xlrds-sheet-ncols) on how to get the equivalent of xlrd's `Sheet.ncols` from COM.

(2) Accessing each cell value TWICE is slowing down both codes. Instead of

```
if ws.cell_value(6, cnum):
    wsHeaders[str(ws.cell_value(6, cnum))] = (cnum, ws.ncols)
```

try

```
value = ws.cell_value(6, cnum)
if value:
    wsHeaders[str(value)] = (cnum, ws.ncols)
```

Note: there are 2 cases of this in each code snippet.

(3) It is not at all apparent what the purpose of your nested loops are, but there does seem to be some redundant computation, involving redundant fetches from COM. If you care to tell us what you are trying to achieve, with examples, we could be able to help you make it run much faster. At the very least, extracting the values from COM once then processing them in nested loops in Python should be faster. How many columns are there?

**Update 2** Meanwhile the little elves took to your code with the proctoscope, and came up with the following script:

```
tests= [
    "A/B/C/D",
    "A//C//",
    "A//C//E",
    "A///D",
    "///D",
    ]
for test in tests:
    print "\nTest:", test
    row = test.split("/")
    ncols = len(row)
    # modelling the OP's code
    # (using xlrd-style 0-relative column indexes)
    d = {}
    for cnum in xrange(ncols):
        if row[cnum]:
            k = row[cnum]
            v = (cnum, ncols) #### BUG; should be ncols - 1 ("inclusive")
            print "outer", cnum, k, '=>', v
            d[k] = v
            for cend in xrange(cnum + 1, ncols):
                if row[cend]:
                    k = row[cnum]
                    v = (cnum, cend - 1)
                    print "inner", cnum, cend, k, '=>', v
                    d[k] = v
                    break
    print d
    # modelling a slightly better algorithm
    d = {}
    prev = None
    for cnum in xrange(ncols):
        key = row[cnum]
        if key:
            d[key] = [cnum, cnum]
            prev = key
        elif prev:
            d[prev][1] = cnum
    print d
    # if tuples are really needed (can't imagine why)
    for k in d:
        d[k] = tuple(d[k])
    print d
```

which outputs this:

```
Test: A/B/C/D
outer 0 A => (0, 4)
inner 0 1 A => (0, 0)
outer 1 B => (1, 4)
inner 1 2 B => (1, 1)
outer 2 C => (2, 4)
inner 2 3 C => (2, 2)
outer 3 D => (3, 4)
{'A': (0, 0), 'C': (2, 2), 'B': (1, 1), 'D': (3, 4)}
{'A': [0, 0], 'C': [2, 2], 'B': [1, 1], 'D': [3, 3]}
{'A': (0, 0), 'C': (2, 2), 'B': (1, 1), 'D': (3, 3)}

Test: A//C//
outer 0 A => (0, 5)
inner 0 2 A => (0, 1)
outer 2 C => (2, 5)
{'A': (0, 1), 'C': (2, 5)}
{'A': [0, 1], 'C': [2, 4]}
{'A': (0, 1), 'C': (2, 4)}

Test: A//C//E
outer 0 A => (0, 5)
inner 0 2 A => (0, 1)
outer 2 C => (2, 5)
inner 2 4 C => (2, 3)
outer 4 E => (4, 5)
{'A': (0, 1), 'C': (2, 3), 'E': (4, 5)}
{'A': [0, 1], 'C': [2, 3], 'E': [4, 4]}
{'A': (0, 1), 'C': (2, 3), 'E': (4, 4)}

Test: A///D
outer 0 A => (0, 4)
inner 0 3 A => (0, 2)
outer 3 D => (3, 4)
{'A': (0, 2), 'D': (3, 4)}
{'A': [0, 2], 'D': [3, 3]}
{'A': (0, 2), 'D': (3, 3)}

Test: ///D
outer 3 D => (3, 4)
{'D': (3, 4)}
{'D': [3, 3]}
{'D': (3, 3)}
```

Comment: +1 I agree - the slowdown is not because of COM but because of the OP's useage of it that makes it seem more slow.

Comment: There are also ways to read and write multiple values to/from Excel using COM via safearrays, precisely because of the IPC overhead. You can do this transparently via win32com, by specifying ranges instead of individual cells.

Comment: I tried to use Range to improve performance but Range and direct access by Cell is the same performance. What bulk read/write are you talking about with Excel COM?

Answer (score 2):

COM requires talking to another process which actually handles the requests. xlrd works in-process on the data structures themselves.

Comment: so is it impossible to do this in a reasonable amount of time, with win32com?

Answer (score 0):

Thought about it as I was going to bed last night, and ended up using this. A far superior version to my original:

```
def makeDict(ws):
"""makes dict with key as header name, 
   value as tuple of column begin and column end (inclusive)"""
wsHeaders = {} # key is header name, value is column begin and end inclusive
last_col = find_last_col(ws)

for cnum in xrange(9, last_col):
    if ws.Cells(7, cnum).Value:
        value = ws.Cells(7, cnum).Value
        cstart = cnum
    if ws.Cells(7, cnum + 1).Value:
        wsHeaders[str(value)] = (cstart, cnum) #cnum is last in range
return wsHeaders
```

Comment: (1) You are still accessing the same cell twice (2) Previous code hardcoded 8th column and 6th row; this one uses 9 and 7 respectively; why?